# Iframes cannot display https on http site, breaks Google API

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-api, google-drive-api

**Information**
I am writing a piece of code that will be going up on a web server that I do not have control over. This webserver does not have `https`. In this code I use the [Google Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/). When I put in the [example code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#SpecifyingyourclientIDandscopes) with all the correct API keys and client ID's and whatnot I get a `Protocols must match` error on an iframe it tries to create to get OAth2 information.

This `Protocols must match` error is of course caused by the fact that the webserver is `http` and the OAth2 url it is using is `https`.

**Main Question**
Is there any way to use Google API's on a server that does not have `https`? Is it possible to shut off this Security feature and make the `https` OAth2 iframe work on a `http` server?

**Note:**
The Google API is creating the iframe that is giving me problems.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating your own iframe. The Google JS library takes care of this for you.

Comment: Yea ik. That's the problem, the iframe it creates doesn't work. It gets blocked.

Comment: There is something else amiss. I use the client library from http origins all the time.

Comment: Could it be with the client ID setup?